# How to display ECHO real-time outputs in the browser Xdebug?

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3, laravel-herd

The real-time outputs are only displayed in the PhpStorm "Output" tab, and only when the script finishes does it display the result in the browser.

This setup didn't work for me:

```ini
implicit_flush=On
output_buffering=0
```

The 'echo' is printed only on this tab:

[image: printed only on this TAB]

**Configuration PhpStorm and php.ini of Laravel Herd**

[image: Configuration php.ini]

Comment: This could just as well be your browser buffering something here. You could also try to explicitly call `flush()` in your PHP script.